# Inserting data to mysql database using PDO with direct insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay hello everyone, I am struggling for days searching and testing my code to work but I always gets an error. The thing is that user will insert their name, last name, email and password but when it's submitted it gives error and that error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 9
```

This is my register.php:

```
try {

    $connect = new PDO( "mysql: host = 'localhost';", 'root', '' );
    $connect->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO users_details.details ( firstname, lastname, email, password ) VALUES (
                 '$_POST['firstName']',
                 '$_POST['lastName']',
                 '$_POST['email']' 
                 '$_POST['password']' )";

    $connect->exec($sqlQuery);
        echo 'Data submitted successfully.';

}

catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

Then this is my database structure: http://prntscr.com/a8uc2b

I can also show you my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
  <!-- Form Name -->
  <legend>
    Data Submission
  </legend>

  <!-- First Name -->
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="firstName">
    </label>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="firstName" name="firstName" pattern="[A-z]+" maxlength="12" data-error="Enter valid first name only." placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
      <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
      </span>
      <div class="help-block with-errors">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Last Name -->
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="lastName">
    </label>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="lastName" name="lastName" pattern="[A-z]+" maxlength="12" data-error="Enter valid last name only." placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
      <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
      </span>
      <div class="help-block with-errors">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- E-Mail -->
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">
    </label>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="email" name="email" maxlength="16" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="email">
      <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
      </span>
      <div class="help-block with-errors">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Password input-->
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="password" name="password" pattern="[A-z0-9!@#$%^*]+" maxlength="25" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
      <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
      </span>
      <div class="help-block with-errors">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Password confirm input-->
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="passwordConfirm">
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" data-match="#password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
      <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
      </span>
      <div class="help-block with-errors">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Button -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit">
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</fieldset>
```

Is it possible to give the values to be insterted in the database be the values that the user inputs in the form? Because I get OC when I still have to declare other things and make my code kinda more long, and yes I accept recommendations and criticism. I am still new in this but I really love efficiency. Much love <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution below should work

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO users_details.details ( firstname, lastname, email, password ) VALUES ('".
             $_POST['firstName'] ."','".
             $_POST['lastName'] ."','".
             $_POST['email'] ."','".
             $_POST['password'] ."')";
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the quick response. Your solution gives me this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 9"

Comment: I updated the code. I was missing the first '.' to perform the concatenation

Comment: It works perfect, thank you so much. It really confuses me a lot tho(those dots and quotes and single quotes). I will try to study it thank you so much Greg!

Answer (score 2):

you can try escaping the quote.

example:

```html
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO users_details.details ( firstname, lastname, email, password ) VALUES ( \' ".$_POST['firstName']." \', \'".$_POST['lastName']."\', \'".$_POST['email']."\'  \'".$_POST['password']."\' )";
```

you can learn more about escaping characters in this [manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: Hello this is what I did: "VALUES (\' '.$_POST[firstName].', '.$_POST[lastName].', '.$_POST['email'].', '.$_POST['password'].' \')";" then it gives me this: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 8"

Comment: that is not how escaping works, okay i'll change my answer to give you the right syntax ... but i noticed that there is a missing ","  in you code near $_POST['email'] maybe that was the problem ... try redoing it with ","

Answer (score 1):

As inferred from the error message, your problem is with this line:

```
    $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO users_details.details ( firstname, lastname, email, password ) VALUES (
                 '$_POST['firstName']',
                 '$_POST['lastName']',
                 '$_POST['email']' 
                 '$_POST['password']' )";
```

This will cause a `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE` error as PHP will take the code as `'$_POST['` and `']'`, due to the usage of single quotes.

Also, you missed out a `,` between `'$_POST['email']'` and `'$_POST['password']'`.

---

A easier and neater way is to assign the `$_POST` to a variable:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO users_details.details ( firstname, lastname, email, password ) VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$password' )";
```

This method would not require the usage of concatenation, thus would minimise errors.

Comment: Hello yes yes this method does work 100% but the thing is that I really want my code to be just minimum like I do not want to declare more variables for this thing to work, more like efficiency sir. Thank you so much tho. I think I like more of it being the values inserted from the user in the form to be the direct values to the VALUES in my sql statement. Thank you!

Comment: if you do not want to declare more variables you should replace all the variable in the single quote example : '$lastName' should be like this ' ".$_POST['firstName']." ' it's all about concatenation.

Comment: :D well  I didn't notice that he missed the concatenation at first :D that's a -1 for me.

Comment: You both helped me, but Greg was very fast in response but you both helped me any buttons to press so I can +1 you two? Hahaha.

Comment: @Fur You can only `+1` if an user has answered on your question, you can do that by clicking the `^` sign above `0`, the down sign is to down vote. You'll need at least 15 reputation to up vote and 125 reputation to down vote ;)